# What if I want to store a None value in the memcache?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, memcached

This is specifically related to the Google App Engine Memcache API, but I'm sure it also applies to other Memcache tools.

The dictionary .get() method allows you to specify a default value, such as dict.get('key', 'defaultval')

This can be useful if it's possible you might want to store None as a value in a dictionary.

However, the memcache.get() does not let you to do this. I've modified my @memoize decorator so it looks like this:

```
def memoize(keyformat, time=1000000):

    """Decorator to memoize functions using memcache."""
    def decorator(fxn):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            key = keyformat + str(args[1:]) + str(kwargs)
            from google.appengine.api import memcache
            data = memcache.get(key)
            if Debug(): return fxn(*args, **kwargs) 
            if data:
                if data is 'None': data =  None
                return data
            data = fxn(*args, **kwargs)
            if data is None: data = 'None' 
            memcache.set(key, data, time)
            return data
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Now I'm sure there's a good argument that I shouldn't be storing None values in the first place, but let's put that aside for now. Is there a better way I can handle this besides converting None vals to strings and back?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A possible way to do this is to create new class that defines `None` for this purpose, and assign instances of this to the cache (unfortunately you cannot extend `None`). Alternatively, you could use the empty string "", or avoid storing None/null values altogether (absence of the key implies None).

Then check for instances of your 'None' class when you check the result of `mc.get(key)` (`is None`, `== ""`, etc)

Comment: I think this is the best approach. It gives you a sentinel value that can't be confused for anything else.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You could do something like what Haskell and Scala does and store an Option dictionary. The dictionary contains two keys: one key to indicate that it is valid and one key that is used to hold the data. Something like this:

```
{valid: true, data: whatyouwanttostore}
```

Then if `get` return None, you know that the cache was missed; if the result is a dictionary with None as the data, the you know that the data was in the cache but that it was false.

Answer (score 0):

Not really.

You could store a None value as an empty string, but there isn't really a way to store special data in a memcache.

What's the difference between the cache key not existing and the cache value being None? It's probably better to unify these two situations.

Comment: Actually, it can be useful to distinguish them. For example, suppose I have a (expensive) way to authenticate users, and I cache the results - the user's details - in memcache. If I get back a 'no such user' response, I probably want to cache that negative response, or else a user can DoS my service by trying to log in with invalid usernames over and over.

Comment: This is exactly the type of situation which I found myself in. Sometimes you want to know that a function returned 'None' but also that it's been done recently enough so that it shouldn't be executed again.